# "No module named xxx" when creating exe with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I had this problem before but solved it by adding something to the pyinstaller command. But now i cant find it, im sure i found the solution here. This is what my command looks like now:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile -w --windowed --icon=icon2.ico main.py
```

From what i remember i had to add the path to Lib/site-packages but i dont remember the exact line. Something like:

```
--paths=venv\Lib\site-packages
```

I have tried different variations of what i remember but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I think you have to reset the virtual environment (if you are using) by just deleting the current one, installing requirements.txt again by using 'pip install -r requirements.txt' , also check the particular package is installed or not.

Comment: Yes i have read about that solution aswell, but i did not have to do that last time, only had to add something like what i wrote and i worked fine.